# mount error(6): No such device or address

Tags: mount, raspberry-pi, fstab, raspbian, nas

I'm trying to mount my NAS server to my raspberry pi server, but without any luck. Mounting a NAS is pretty new to me.

my fstab:

`//10.0.0.15/volume1/pie /home/nas/ cifs username=pie,password=pieserver,workgroup=WORKGROUP`

But when I try to run `mount -a` then I get this error:

`root@pi2:/home/pi# mount -a
Retrying with upper case share name
mount error(6): No such device or address
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)`

I can reach the NAS server without problems from my desktop, but the pi can't seem to find it.

What can I do?

I've tried searching the net for solutions, and tried most of them, but most of them are just different strings to insert into `/etc/fstab`. But again, I had no luck.

Comment: Well, the obvious troubleshooting step is to test whether 1. you can mount it manually from the command line (without invoking fstab), 2. you can reach the server at all (via ssh/ping).

Comment: Mounting though CLI gives the sames error. And I am able to ping it.

Comment: does `/volume1/pie` exist as an exported share on your NAS?  Try `smbclient -U pie -L 10.0.0.15` to list the shares available to user pie.  if it's not already installed, you'll need to install the `smbclient` package to do this.

Comment: That works fine, asking for password and outputted this: http://pastie.org/private/urgvev9qocxhtdu81cdew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem found & fixed.

Was wrong dir path on NAS server, I used the path for admin user which is full path, but since pie only has access to the pi folder, then it just "direct" connect to that folder.